# Change default text color in Docusaurus v2

Tags: html, css, docusaurus

In [Docusaurus v2](https://v2.docusaurus.io) I can override the default text color for each class as:

```
.features {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

I don't like this approach because it makes it harder to define separate colors for the `dark` and `light` theme.

By default the text color is set to `black` in `light` theme, and `white` in `dark` theme. However, I cannot seem to find where these are defined.

- I am interested in modifying these defaults, where are they defined?
- Is this the recommended way of styling the default text color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the browser to inspect HTML and see which CSS variables affect the text color.

Modify the `var(--ifm-font-color-base)` color by adding the following CSS to `custom.css`.

```css
:root {
  --ifm-font-color-base: #000;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore, as of v2.0.0-beta.13 at least.

Comment: Docusaurus 2.0.0, I can confirm it is working.